# Actualizar MVC Codeigniter 4 , sin rellenar obligatoriamente todos los campos

Tags: php, base-de-datos, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de actualizar mi tabla con esta función, sin el proceso de validación guarda correctamente mis datos, no necesito cambiar todos los datos a editar es decir si deseo puedo cambiar un solo dato, pero si deseo validar me obliga a rellenar todos los campos, como puedo actualizar y que valide sin rellenar todos los campos??

```
 public function actualizar($id = null)
    {
        helper('text');

        $users = new UserModel();

         $validacion = $this->validate([
            'nif'           => 'regex_match[/^([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])[0-9]{7}([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9])$/]',
            'email'         => 'valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]',
            'confpassword'  => 'matches[password]'
        ]); 

            $datos = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_surname'     => $this->request->getVar('surname'),
                'user_enterprise'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
                'user_nif'     => $this->request->getVar('nif'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'id_rol'    => $this->request->getVar('id_rol'),
                'user_accept'    => $this->request->getVar('user_accept'),
                'user_password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
            ];

            if($validacion){
            $users->update($id,$datos); 
        }
        
     return $this->response->redirect(site_url('/admin/usersList'));
    }
```

Adjunto imagen de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si el codigo lo hago de este modo guarda correctamente y puedo editar campos sueltos.

```
 public function actualizar($id = null)
    {
        helper('text');

        $users = new UserModel();

            $datos = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_surname'     => $this->request->getVar('surname'),
                'user_enterprise'     => $this->request->getVar('enterprise'),
                'user_nif'     => $this->request->getVar('nif'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email'),
                'id_rol'    => $this->request->getVar('id_rol'),
                'user_accept'    => $this->request->getVar('user_accept'),
                'user_password' => password_hash($this->request->getVar('password'), PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
            ];


            $users->update($id,$datos); 

        
     return $this->response->redirect(site_url('/admin/usersList'));
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo están los campos en la Base de Datos? ¿Están definidos ahí como obligatorios? ¿El error es en la validación directa del modelo o es provocado por la Base de Datos?

Comment: @VFG he añadido una imagend e la base de datos, diria que no están obligatorios ya que si no realizo la validación puedo editar y guardar campos sueltos, pero al colocar la validación si o si requiere que edite toodos los campos juntos.